# Select multiple elements with similar ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to minimise this code:

```
$('#thistext0').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
$('#thistext1').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
$('#thistext2').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
$('#thistext3').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
```

Is something like this possible in JS?

```
$('#thistext[i]').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
```

If so, how?

**EDIT:**
I cannot use classes because the way I am looping through records with PHP, I have to use IDs

Comment: Have you heard of classes? http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: It had to be ID because of the way I am looping through records with PHP. I did not mention this before because I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: Well, I guess you could still add a class to the elements when you are generating them dynamically anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A startswith selector is possible, or use a common classname.

```
$("[id^='thistext']").keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
```

While using startwith selector provide a parent container as context for safety i.e `$("[id^='thistext']", 'container')`

Also do remember that this will be slower than native id or class selector as this is an attribute selector.

**[attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

So providing a common classname to all of those textboxes and selecting then using the classSelector would be ideal i believe.

Comment: This is perfect, as per my Q edit - I cannot use classes due to the way I am looping through records with PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, but this is possible:

```
$('#thistext0, #thistext1, #thistext2, #thistext3').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
});
```

Of course, the selector string can be created in a loop. Or just add a class to your input fields, and select by class.

Comment: Now that I see PSL's answer, I believe `[id^='thistext']` is a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Use **[jQuery's starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** attribute selector:

```
$('[id^="thistext"]').keyup(function(e){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
});
```